# immediately calling custom action when uninstalling program

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action

I've a question aboud a custom action that needs to take place during an uninstall. currently I have the custom action working for the biggest part, however there is a small problem.

The custom action needs to take place immediately after the uninstall option is selected since it contains the command to force the running program( installed with the same installer) to close and some other commands for other tasks. bud currently the WIX installer tries to close the program by itself which it is unable to. that means my custom action as well as the rest of the uninstall will fail.

currently I have this code bud it is not working at the point I would like it to.

```
 <CustomAction
      Id="UninstallScript"
      Directory="INSTALLFOLDER"
      ExeCommand="[INSTALLFOLDER]De-installation script.exe"
      Execute="commit"
      Return="check">
    </CustomAction>
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="UninstallScript" Before="InstallInitialize"> Installed AND NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE AND NOT REINSTALL </Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

any idea how I can make it work the way I intended?

**note:** if I manually close the running program and then run the uninstall option it works fine. which means the timing of my function needs to be moved forward. also the running program starts when Windows boots up which means it won't show the desktop bud directly shows the program ( this is intentionally ).

thanks in advance,

Comment: If you need this to run as soon as the option is selected, perhaps you should incorporate it into the GUI. Dialogs and controls can call custom actions.

Comment: thanks for the reply. that is an option, however I dont know how to do that, so that will take some research to make it work.